# Python AttributeError: module has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, type-annotation

I have a python module file which has a bunch of class definition along with its method sample.py

```
def abc():
    ...
class Sampler(object):
    def foo(self):
       ...
class Sampler2(object):
     def bar(self):
         ...
```

Now I want to import this file into another python file and use type annotations while defining a function like below: say samplers.py

```
import sample
 class Xyz(object):
      def foobar(self, sampleparam:sample.Sampler)-> int :
            ...
```

The above is throwing AttributeError: module 'sample' has no attribute 'Sampler'. Is the above implementation incorrect ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  def foobar(self, sample:sample.Sampler)-> int :
```

> AttributeError: module 'sample' has no attribute 'Sampler'.

The formal parameter is named `sample`, yet you imported `sample`. Rename the formal parameter (perhaps to `sample_`), or use this syntax:

```
from sample import Sampler
...
    def foobar(self, sample: Sampler) -> int:
```

Cf https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references, which explains that the use of string literals is also supported. Here, using symbols would be the most appropriate approach.

Comment: Sorry about the poor choice of examples param name. I have updated the example provided